# OpenCv videoCapture in cpanel (Incomplete response received from application)

Tags: django, video, video-capture, opencv, python

Here I call Videocamera to open the camera and then return streaminghttpresponse and there i call gen(cam). Now i am facing 2 problem. i want to store 100 images of user and go back to another screen. here this code working locally fine but when i upload it on server its give error Incomplete response received from application and second problem is will render to another screen when count == 10

```
def getImages(request):
    global postReq
    postReq = request
    print(request)
    global userRequest 
    global userFaceName
    userFaceName = request.POST['name']
    print(userFaceName)
    userRequest = request.user.pk
    print(userRequest)
    try:
        cam = VideoCamera()
        print("hello check")
        return StreamingHttpResponse(gen(cam), content_type="multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=frame")
       
        
    except:
        print("killed")
        pass
    return redirect('imagess')

class VideoCamera():
    def __init__(self):
        global count
        print("video camera")
        self.video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        print("video")
        (self.grabbed, self.frame) = self.video.read()
        
        threading.Thread(target=self.update, args=()).start()
        
        

    def __del__(self):
        print("destriy")
        self.video.release()



    
    def get_frame(self):
       
        face_id=1
        image = self.frame
        # face_detector = cv2.CascadeClassifier('C:\\Users\\abbas\\Desktop\\final 
        try\\FYP\\isight\\Application\\haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        # faces = face_detector.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
        
        # for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        #     cv2.rectangle(gray, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (255,0,0), 2)
        #     global count
        #     count = count + 1
        #     face = cv2.resize(image, (400, 400))
        #     face = cv2.cvtColor(face, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        #     writePic = cv2.imwrite("static/pdfbook/images/User." + str(face_id) + '.' + str(count) 
        + ".jpg", gray[y:y+h,x:x+w])
        #     c = 'C:\\Users\\abbas\\Desktop\\final try\\FYP\\isight\\static\\pdfbook\\images\\' + 
        "User." + str(face_id) + '.' + str(count) + ".jpg"
        #     Image.objects.create(User=User.objects.get(id=userRequest)  , name = userFaceName , 
        imagestore = c )
        #     print(count)
            
        # if cv2.waitKey(100) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        #     self.video.release()
        # # If image taken reach 100, stop taking video
```

**here when count == 100 i want to render to another view but deo to streaminghttpresponse i did not render**

```
        # elif count==100:
        #     faceNumberEnd=FaceName.objects.all().count()
        #     faceNumberEnd = faceNumberEnd + 1
        #     self.video.release()
        #     self.stopped = True
        #     global postReq
        #     FaceName.objects.create(User=User.objects.get(id=userRequest) , name= userFaceName ,ids 
        #= faceNumberEnd)
        #     return 
            
        _, jpeg = cv2.imencode('.jpg', gray)
        
        return jpeg.tobytes()

    def update(self):
        while True:
            (self.grabbed, self.frame) = self.video.read()




def gen(camera):
    while True:
        
        
        

        frame = camera.get_frame()
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
            b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n\r\n')
```